# Windows Configuration Designer wont deploy appx packages

Tags: windows

I am trying to deploy an appx package using Windows Configuration Designer and I am at my wits end on trying things for this.

## Description:

- Windows Configuration Designer fails at deploying appx Device Context App
  [Logs](https://mega.nz/folder/BIsSVKAL#NnFO-9y3broq0K4_ddNv1Q)

## **Tested and failed so far:**

1. Rewiping and redploying the machine
2. Installing an app that simply echo's a string into a file (no dependencies)
3. Installing Powershell7 (no dependencies)
4. Installed these on main machine, they work
5. Installed after deploying the machine after taking out the appx packages from the deployment, they worked

## **Expected:**

- Deploy the appx to the device